# django-filter: add "All" filter option for AllValuesFilter with LinkWidget

Tags: django, django-filter, wagtail

Filtering with [django-filter](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter) with an `AllValuesFilter` on a many-to-many field and displaying this via `LinkWidget`, I don't get an `All` filter option, as with the django admin `list_filter`.

I've found [Add Any & None Handling to ChoiceFilter (and subclasses)](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/261) and various other related issues, but I don't get the solution...

In this specific case, I'm filtering on categories for a Django [Wagtail](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail) `Page` model:

```
# models.py

# wagtail imports
# ...
# modelcluster imports, eg.
# from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey, ParentalManyToManyField

class CategoryRegion(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,)

class NewsPage(Page):
    categories_region = ParentalManyToManyField(
        "core.CategoryRegion", 
        blank=True,
     )
```

--

```
# filters.py

import django_filters
from django_filters.widgets import LinkWidget

class NewsFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    categories_region = django_filters.AllValuesFilter(
        name="categories_region__title", 
        label="Categories: Region",
        widget=LinkWidget(),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = NewsPage
        fields = ['categories_region',]
```

Any hints?

Comment: I'd suggest trying to replicate this on a fresh (non-Wagtail) project using a plain `ManyToManyField` rather than a `ParentalManyToManyField`. Modelcluster's field types rely on obscure and not-entirely-stable Django internals, so that'll help determine whether those Modelcluster quirks are to blame, or whether this is a pure `django-filter` issue (in which case I can't help, but hopefully someone else will...)

Comment: Ok, I will try that. Interestingly, hooking up a `ModelAdmin` on this page model and setting `categories_region` as a  `list_filter`, I'll get the `All` option in this `ModelAdmin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [bug](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/pull/134#issuecomment-284067570) where `AllValuesFilter` does not have an all/any option. [#680](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/pull/680) should fix the issue, but it's currently unmerged. In the meantime, you should be able to install the related branch for the PR, or create a custom subclass that adds the "All" option. Something like:

```
class ActuallyAllValuesFilter(django_filters.AllValuesFilter):

    @property
    def field(self):
        f = super(ActuallyAllValuesFilter, self).field
        f.choices = [('', 'All')] + f.choices
        return f
```